# Problem with dual-view

Tags: nvidia

I've just installed 12.04 LTS on my old IBM ThinkPad R51 and I connected Samsung Syncmaster 21.5" monitor via VGA port.

I've tried to do dual-view, but when I try to set a resolution on a monitor, which is bigger then laptop's resolution, I got an error:

```
The selected configuration for displays could not be applied.  
Requested position/size for CRTC 63 is outside the allowed limit:
position=(1024, 0), size=(1920, 1080), maximum=(2048, 2048).
```

When I try to launch nvidia-settings, it says:

```
You do not appear to be using the nvidia x server.
```

I've tried to install newest Nvidia drivers etc. but that didn't help.

What should I do, to use 1920x1080 resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting up the displays as 2 separate x-screens you can run `sudo nvidia-settings` in terminal, choose the second option down on the left, I would think that might be useful for you.

Also if the laptop is old it may not support or have the power to display at 1920x1080, especial if it uses Intel gma graphics.

Comment: Well when I try to launch nvidia-settings, it says: "“You do not appear to be using the nvidia x server"

Comment: It just seems like your laptop cannot display at 1920x1080 if this is wrong then all I can suggest is using a diffrent type of cable like dvi or hdmi sorry cant help more